# Where am I making a mistake in manipulating this inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I have $dn-2cn+c \ge 0$

**Method 1 -**

$dn-c(2n-1) \ge 0$

$c(2n-1) \le dn$

$c \le \frac{dn}{2n-1}$

**Method 2 -**

$dn + c(1-2n) \ge 0$

$c(1-2n) \ge -dn$

$c \ge \frac{-dn}{1-2n}$

$c \ge \frac{dn}{2n-1}$

I am unable to point out a mistake in any of the above two methods yet their results are opposite of each other. Please tell me where am I making a mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1 is correct if $2n-1\geq 0$, otherwise incorrect.

Method 2 is correct if $1-2n\geq 0$, otherwise incorrect.

The direction of an inequality is preserved only if you divide by a positive number.

Answer (score 1):

The question is whether $2n-1$ is positive.

Remember that sign of inequality switches when we multiply or divide by a negative number.